# Scrolling PrimeNG datatable on mobile devices in Angular 2

Tags: angular, mobile, datatable, vertical-scrolling, primeng

Currently I'm using a PrimeNG datatable in Angular 2 to display a list of documents. This should work for a mobile device, so I used the responsive one. When clicking one row of the datatable, another component with the details of the document is shown.

We deployed the datatable to our server and tested it on a mobile device. The problem here is that when scrolling on the datatable, the document details screen immediately is shown. In other words, when touching a row to be able to scroll, the document details screen is opened. When scrolling next to the datatable, we can actually scroll, but that's a really small area. Someone with fat fingers will easily miss.

Could someone point me in the right direction to be able to scroll on the datatable itself without the document details screen being opened?

In addition, this is the code I'm using to show the datatable:

```
<p-dataTable class="table table-striped" [value]="visibleRows" sortMode="multiple" reorderableColumns="true" [responsive]="true" selectionMode="single" (onRowSelect)="onRowSelect($event)">
    <p-column *ngFor="let column of visibleColumns" [field]="column.key" [header]="column.name" [sortable]="true"></p-column>
</p-dataTable>
```

The event is just routing to the document details screen, nothing more.

If you need any more information, feel free to ask.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this by removing the (onRowSelected) event, and putting some kind of button to open the row only when clicked. Possibly in the header of the row.